# Query Result export per email

Tags: delimiter, xls, nocount

I Try to export the Query result per E-Mail as Attach

***here the code:***

```
DECLARE @Delimiter Char(1)

SET @Delimiter = CHAR(9)
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'MyProfile',
@recipients = 'myemailaad@mail.com',
@subject = 'Defects Total Value',
@body='MyText',
@query= 'MyQuery',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1,
@query_result_no_padding=1,
@Query_Result_Header = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Results.xls',
@query_result_separator =@Delimiter
```

it work normally but I have two issues:

1. The second row is empty : how deletet it(in the query)?
2. In the Query i use : SET NOCOUNT ON,
   but in the xls file I can see the count (see screenshot), 
   how deletet it(in the query)?

Thanks in advance

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPZlL.png][1]

Answer (score 0):

the second issue is solved :no count in the result
the "set NOCOUNT on; must be in the query and not only in the stored procedure.
@Query='set NOCOUNT on;select....'

if the "SET NOCOUNT ON;" is only in the Sp  like this:

```
   AS

   BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

it isn't enough to not returned the count